# How to add an id element to a field in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I am try to find out a way that I can add in #ID element to a link field in Drupal 7. When you Edit the field it give you a chance to create a CLASS (Additional CSS Class) for it, however I want to add an #ID element so that I can use it to trigger an event for google analytics. I actually was able to add and #ID to that panel display but it is 2  above and not triggering it.

Is there a way to do this without code, if not what approach would I take to handle through code(not my specialty).
Here is an example of what I have...

```
<div class="panel-pane pane-entity-field pane-node-field-print-link"  id="newsletterPrint">
  <div class="pane-content">
    <div class="field-print-link">
      <a href="http://stage.ecgcme.com/print/project/MTH095AE1">Print</a>  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and I want this...

```
<div class="field-print-link" id="newsletterPrint">
          <a href="http://stage.ecgcme.com/print/project/MTH095AE1">Print</a>  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all are you using the Link module? Just so we know.

I would create a template to the field:

You can copy the `/modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php` to your theme, change the name to `field--field-print-link.tpl.php` and customize it in any way wanted.

Don't forget to flush your caches!

Or, of course, you could add the id with JS using a bit of jQuery (as Drupal already uses it):

```
$('element').attr('id', 'value');
```

Comment: Lauro - Thanks! Yes we are using the link module. I will look into both and try it out. Appreciate your assistance!